# How to iterate an array in an interface{}?

Tags: arrays, loops, dictionary, go

i have a map

```
myMap := make(map[string]interface{})
```

one of this map elements is array of []map[string]string

```
myMap["element"] = []map[string]string
```

how can i iterate this array?

Comment: Type assert `[]map[string]string` from that element, which you can loop over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't iterate over a value of type `interface{}`, which is the type you'll get returned from a lookup on any key in your map (since it has type `map[string]interface{}`).

You should use a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to obtain a value of that type, over which you can then range.

```
myElt := myMap["element"]
v, ok := myElt.([]map[string]string)
if !ok {
    // TODO: Handle the error
}

for i, item := range v {
    // TODO: do something with each map[string]string item in the slice
}
```

Here's a [working playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/-EgpirlTq1k) using a contrived setup for those map types.

---

If you know the value is of the specified slice type, you can omit the `ok` check in the type assertion. This might be the case if you are using someone else's generic map implementation (which has keys of type `interface{}`) and know you only ever populate it with values of type `[]map[string]string`. However, exercise caution: if you obtain a value *not* of this type from the map, and you omit the check, your program will panic.